# No puedo obtener el contenido de un json en REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

Hola gente estoy queriendo obtener el contenido del json el un componente en react, en este caso el componente es una carta entonces, primero le hago un fetch al json y luego automaticamente me generaría 6 cartas con la informacion de cada dato que esta en el json, pero, cuando hago un console,log para verificar que este bien, no me sale nada, el primer console log si me salen los datos, pero a la hora de recorrerlos me sale en blanco

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from 'axios';

function Card() {
    const [carta, setCarta] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        axios
            .get('/cartas.json')
            .then((response) =>
                 setCarta(response.data))
            .catch((err) => console.log(err))
    }, []);
console.log(carta)
    return (
        Array.from(carta).forEach((car) =>{
            console.log(car.cita.nombre)
        })
        )
//         {
//             carta,map((card, index) => (
//                 <div className="card">
//                     <img
//                         src={card.imagen}
//                         alt={card.nombre}
//                     />
//                     <div className="card-body">
//                         <p className="card-title">{card.descripcion}</p>
//                     </div>
//                     <div className="card-footer">
//                         <Link to={"/" + card.nombre} className=" text-white">{card.nombre}</Link>
//                     </div>
//                 </div>
//             ))
//         }
     
 };

export default Card;
```

este es el json donde tengo los datos

```
    `{
    "cita": [
        {
        "id": 1,
        "imagen": "../assets/citas.png",
        "nombre": "Citas",
        "descripcion": "En esta sección puedes reservar los días de asistencia de los clientes"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "imagen": "../assets/historial.png",
        "nombre": "Historial",
        "descripcion": "En esta sección contiene todo el historial de la clinica"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "imagen": "../assets/listaClientes.png",
        "nombre": "Listado de clientes",
        "descripcion": "En esta sección contiene el listado de clientes de la clinica"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "imagen": "../assets/mascotas.png",
        "nombre": "Mascotas",
        "descripcion": "Esta sección contiene toda la información de las mascotas registradas en la clinica"
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "imagen": "../assets/registrar.png",
        "nombre": "Registrar",
        "descripcion": "En esta sección se puede registrar a un cliente nuevo"
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "imagen": "../assets/roles.png",
        "nombre": "Roles",
        "descripcion": "En esta sección puedes ver los roles que tiene cada usuario que accede a la aplicacion"
    }
]
```

}`

Y este es el resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se muestra el ultimo console.log

Corregido el problema, pero ahora no sale la carta

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from 'axios';

function Card() {
    const [carta, setCarta] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('../cartas.json')
            .then(response => {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(data => {
                //console.log(data.cita)
                setCarta(data);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err.message)
            });
    }, []);
    render();{
        return (
            Array.from(carta).forEach((card) => {
                return (
                    // console.log(card.descripcion);
                    <div className="car">
                        <img
                            src={card.imagen}
                            alt={card.nombre}
                        />
                        <div className="card-body">
                            <p className="card-title">{card.descripcion}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div className="card-footer">
                            <Link to={"/" + card.nombre} className=" text-white">{card.nombre}</Link>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )
            })
        )
    }
};
```

Comment: Creo que tienes problemas con el tiempo de respuesta que tarda tu peticion axios, podrias probar con una funcion asincrona, o usar otro `useEffect` y en el [array de dependencias](https://www.matiashernandez.dev/blog/post/react-useeffect-por-que-el-arreglo-de-dependencias-es-importante) pasandole `carta` como dependencia para que efectue acciones cada vez que `carta` cambie de valor.

Comment: no entiendo, te refieres a hacer dos useEffect?

Comment: si, lo que pasa es que si lo pones en el useEffect que tienes crearia un bucle infinito, puedes crear otro useEffect que ejecute ciertas accciones si su variable de dependencia cambia.

Comment: lo hice con un fetch normal, lo que pasa que ahora no me aparece la carta, te lo muestro arriba

Comment: @informaticoDudas creo que la carta no está saliendo porque el render se hace sobre un array que en un momento, se encuentra nulo o vacio. Podes envolver el return en un ``if(carta.length)`` o bien despues del return hacer ``carta.length && Array.from(carta).forEach(...``

Comment: @informaticoDudas consulta, porque creas un nuevo array a partir del state ``carta``? No seria mas performante iterar directamente sobre ``carta``?  ``carta.length && carta.forEach( card => ...``

Comment: con respecto a esta ultima pregunta, es porque vi un ejemplo en internet, y probé, react no lo controlo mucho, y mas si quiero traer datos del lado backend, por eso lo hice

Comment: y respondiendote a la otra pregunta, hice lo que me dijiste y aun no me sale la carta

Comment: if (carta.length) {
        return (
            Array.from(carta).forEach((card) => {
                return (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema es que estás tratando de iterar un objeto no un arreglo, según el JSON que colocaste, tu api retorna un objeto con la propiedad cita que es un arreglo, por lo que debes iterar el arreglo, no el objeto. Me refiero a que lo que tu api retorna es:

```
{
  "cita": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "imagen": "../assets/citas.png",
      "nombre": "Citas",
      "descripcion": "En esta sección puedes reservar los días de asistencia de los clientes"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "imagen": "../assets/historial.png",
      "nombre": "Historial",
      "descripcion": "En esta sección contiene todo el historial de la clinica"
    }
  ]
}
```

Y en el return tratas de iterar carta.

Tienes dos opciones, o, al asignar el valor de carta en tu useEffect usas:

```
setCarta(data.cita);
```

o...

en tu return accedes a carta.cita:

```
{(carta?.cita && carta?.cita.length > 0) ? Array.from(carta.cita).forEach((card) => {
                return (
                    // console.log(card.descripcion);
                    <div className="car">
                        <img
                            src={card.imagen}
                            alt={card.nombre}
                        />
                        <div className="card-body">
                            <p className="card-title">{card.descripcion}</p>
                        </div>
                        <div className="card-footer">
                            <Link to={"/" + card.nombre} className=" text-white">{card.nombre}</Link>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )
            }) : null }
```

En resumen el problema es que estás accediendo a la propiedad equivocada.

Comment: si me sirvio tu respuesta, gracias, ahora, no se porque no me sale la carta, porque por consola si me sale la informacion, pero a la hora de pintar la carta en el dom, no me sale nada